# How to remove the inner border of a Widget in a Stack in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: Goal]

[image: Example]

I wan't to get the outline border of two containers in a Stack, one positioned like the image suggest. My goal is to remove the "red" part.

How can I accomplish this in Flutter?

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(),
          ),
          child: const Center(child: Text("BLABLABLA")),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: -10,
          left: 10,
          child: Container(
            width: 150,
            height: 25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(),
            ),
            child: const Center(child: Text("BLABLABL2")),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide your code

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: You need output same as the first image, right?

Comment: yeah, without the red border.

Comment: @Nauzet Can you post your code?

Comment: @LapaNyAinaTanjona the code is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, then this would work for you!

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Stack Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                border: Border.all(),
              ),
              child: const Center(child: Text("BLABLABLA")),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: -10,
              left: 10,
              child: Container(
                width: 150,
                height: 25,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Stack(children: [
                  Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                          top: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                          left: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                          right: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                      height: 11),
                  Center(
                    child: Text("BLABLABL2"),
                  ),
                ],
               ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The output will be like,

[image]